# Docker - Can't seem to get PDO drivers to work

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've been trying to setup a couple of images that I require for my project.
Among these are nginx and php 7.4 with pdo_mysql.

I'm using the official PHP and NGINX images, but my website says that it can't find my PDO drivers.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
     - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
     - ./api:/usr/share/nginx/www
     - /root/.ssh/id_rsa:/data/web/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
     - /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/data/web/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:cached
    ports:
     - "8081:80"
    environment:
     - NGINX_HOST=*
     - NGINX_PORT=80
     - NGINX_ROOT=/usr/share/nginx/www
    links:
     - php
  php:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: php
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/share/nginx/www
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen ${NGINX_PORT};
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name *;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root ${NGINX_ROOT};

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

php -m result:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: Did you share your `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` exactly as they are ?

Comment: @AymDev I only took the NGINX_HOST out by replacing it with a *

Comment: Also, make sure you rebuild your images after making these changes. These problems are often caused when an old(er) image is being used but you think you're using the latest one. If you're using compose, then `docker compose up --build --force-recreate`

Comment: @waterloomatt Thank you but i've already done that everytime i edited my files

Comment: Hang on, is that your entire _docker-compose.yml_ file? Normally, you specify where to find your Dockerfile using `build` or `context` or `dockerfile`. Are you sure it is using your Dockerfile? Try breaking it by typing in invalid syntax and rebuilding it. If it builds OK then it is not detecting your Dockerfile. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build

Comment: What exactly is not working with that? What have you tried to resolve the problem (like rebuilding your containers, or checking that all parts of the configuration are really used)? Is nginx really related here?

Comment: @NicoHaase I did rebuild my containers, it just doesn't seem to pick up my modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are not building any Docker image with the PDO extensions. You may have a **Dockerfile** but your **docker-compose.yml** does not tell Docker Compose to use it to build your `php` service as you have a `image` key pointing to the official `php:7.4-fpm` image.

To build it, replace the `image` section with a [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) one:

```yaml
services:
    # ...
    php:
        build:
            context: .
        # ...
```

Your image will be built on the next `docker-compose run`. Then open a shell inside the container and run `php -m` to see PDO listed.

The second issue will be your **Dockerfile** itself which only has a `RUN` instruction. To base your image on the `php:7.4-fpm` one, add a [FROM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) instruction at the beginning:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN ...
```

Comment: Hello, i updated my post and gave more info, i'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows - remove `image: php:7.4-fpm` from docker-compose.yml. It will use your Dockerfile instead.

Comment: You still have the `image` section in your Docker Compose file, I think you should remove it and run `docker-compose build php`.

Comment: @AymDev Okay so i commented out #image and left the rest as in my question, it seemed to be doing a lot and i now have a new issue: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /usr/share/nginx/www/core/db.class.php:53